# WPF binding with observerableCollection doesnt work

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I use for my WPF project a `binding` of a table (db) to a `listview`. But if i start my project, the listview is empty. Iam using linq to get the data of my entity-framework and `address` has definitly the right string in it.
Is my binding is wrong and how to fix it?

**xaml**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="lstvw_Overview" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Adresse" 
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding structureAddress}"/>     
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

**code**
*Iam pretty sure that my table is filled*

```
Public Sub New()
    Initialize()
End Sub

 Dim address As String

 Public Structure Uebersicht
    Dim structureAddress As String
    Shared _items As ObservableCollection(Of Uebersicht) = New ObservableCollection(Of Uebersicht)
    Public Property Items As ObservableCollection(Of Uebersicht)
        Get
            Return _items
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of Uebersicht))
            _items = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Structure

 Sub Initialize()
    InitializeComponent()
    DataContext = Me
    fillListView()
End Sub

Sub fillListView()
    Using container As New infrastrukturDB_TESTEntities1
        Dim mailAddressList = From tbl_unzustellbarAdressen In container.tbl_unzustellbarAdressen
        For Each mail In mailAddressList
            address = mail.unzustellbarMail.ToString()
            Try
                Uebersicht._items.Add(New Uebersicht With {.structureAddress = address})
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("error")
            End Try
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is missing important parts.

Comment: @grek40 which parts? i shortened it a bit for the question

Comment: Well you define the structure `Uebersicht` but I don't see where you create an instance of this structure. But the more I think of it, maybe the problem is not that you posted incomplete code but that your code is incomplete (being the problem you ask about)

Comment: @grek40 ah.. how do i create an instance of structure? with Dim structure As new Structure Uebersicht?

Comment: @grek i already create an instance of Uebersicht in my try catch

Comment: Yea, I get your problem. Don't know if I'll find time to write a detailed solution, so I will probably start with some more high-level structure explanation.

Comment: @grek40 i am looking forward to ur solution, dont hesitate i work atm on an other part of my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WPF bindings, always provide a `Property` definition, fields are not supported by the `Binding` class. So you need to turn `structureAddress` into a property in order to make it work.

Since you set your Window (?) class instance as its own `DataContext` and try to bind `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"`, your window class needs to contain a `Property` named `Items` with some collection type (eg `ObservableCollection`). So move your collection from within `Structure Uebersicht` to the outer Window class and don't use `Shared` on the backing field.

Note you don't really need the property setter on `Items` since you initialize `_items` once and then you only ever modify the contained items but not the collection reference itself.

Comment: iam not sure if i understand u right. 1) i need to change `structureAddress` from `Dim` to `Public Property` ? 2) ill take everything inside of my structure outside and change `shared _items` to ???

Comment: @Raizzen You only keep `structureAddress` as property inside the structure. But you move the collection out of the structure, since the collection **item type** is your structure type. Then, when your items collection is inside your window class, there is just not any reason to have it `Shared` it can be a simple instance field.

Comment: ok got it. what about shared _items? do i have to change shared too? and i dont have to change `structureAddress` at all right.. iam sry

Comment: @Raizzen seriously, here is some advice: *read, understand, try, read again, ask if anything is unclear* Please don't skip the steps 2,3 and 4.